# How do I turn a specific group of items in a list into a desired item

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So basically I have this list.

`[4097, add, 1, divide, blank, subtract, 3, floor, 1, add, 2, multiply, 8]`

With this list I'm trying to attempt to turn `[blank, subtract, 3]` into `[-3]`.

It interprets a negative number to an equations that has a subtract sign with a blank left operand.

Any way to combine `[blank, subtract, 3]` into `[-3]`? Or even `[blank, add, 3]` into `[3]`?

Comment: Are the list items grouped in any way? Is this supposed to be a reverse Polish calculator? What does `blank` represent (does it mean "clear the accumulator")?

Comment: Assign a list slice.  `mylist[4:7] = [-3]`

Answer (score 0):

you will need to iterate through the list in order to delete what you do not want, and add what you want, there is no automatic way of to replace three items into one, but that can be doned with a simple function

```
def replace_blank(blank_list):
for idx in range(0,len(blank_list)-3):
    if blank_list[idx] == 'blank':
        if blank_list[idx+1] == 'subtract':
            blank_list.pop(idx) #delete at that index
            blank_list.pop(idx)
            blank_list[idx] = '-' + blank_list[idx]
        elif blank_list[idx+1] == 'add':
            blank_list.pop(idx)
            blank_list.pop(idx)
        #.... any other operations i may want to add
            
return blank_list
```

list_bla = ['4097', 'add', '1', 'divide', 'blank', 'subtract', '3', 'floor', '1', 'add', '2', 'multiply', '8']
print(replace_blank(list_bla))

edits proposed by @nokla. The idea of this function is to be O(1) in space complexity.

Comment: It is a bad idea to remove items from a list while iterating through it.. In addition, it is not recommended to use reserved words like `list` as variables as it can lead to naming conflicts.

Comment: You should also run the code before you post it... This code has some errors in it (for example in python comments are done by `#` , `//` will lead to errors). Even if you remove all the comments, the functions still won't do what asked in the question..

Comment: You are correct in all you said. The idea of removing items from a list while iterating through it is to save space by avoiding the creation of another list.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the list using a loop and then check for specific keywords.

#### For example:

- It is unclear what is `blank` representing, I used it as a separator between expressions..

```
def calc_list(lst):
    new_lst = [0]
    action_before = 'add'
    for i in lst:
        if i == 'blank':
            new_lst.append(0)
        elif i.isdigit():
            num = int(i)
            if action_before == 'add':
                new_lst[-1] += num
            elif action_before == 'subtract':
                new_lst[-1] -= num
            elif action_before == 'multiply':
                new_lst[-1] *= num
            elif action_before == 'divide':
                new_lst[-1] /= num
        else:
            action_before=i
    
    return new_lst
            

    
lst1 = ['blank', 'subtract', '3']
lst2 = ['4097', 'add', '1', 'divide', 'blank', 'subtract', '3','add', '1', 'add', '5', 'multiply', '8']
print(calc_list(lst2))
print(calc_list(lst1))
```

#### Output:

```
[-3]
[4098, 24]
```

### Edit:

If blank isn't doing anything you can simply ignore it and move on:

```
def calc_list(lst):
    new_lst = [0]
    action_before = 'add'
    for i in lst:
        if i == 'blank':
            continue
            # new_lst.append(0)
        elif i.isdigit():
            num = int(i)
            if action_before == 'add':
                new_lst[-1] += num
            elif action_before == 'subtract':
                new_lst[-1] -= num
            elif action_before == 'multiply':
                new_lst[-1] *= num
            elif action_before == 'divide':
                new_lst[-1] /= num
        else:
            action_before=i
    
    return new_lst
            

    
lst1 = ['blank', 'subtract', '3']
lst2 = ['4097', 'add', '1', 'blank', 'subtract', '3','add', '1', 'add', '5', 'multiply', '8']
print(calc_list(lst2))
print(calc_list(lst1))
```

#### Output:

```
[32808]
[-3]
```

Comment: blank is basically, well blank. The thing is that my program makes `[1, subtract, 2]` out of `"1 - 2"`, however in this case " - 3" would be `[blank, subtract, 3]`, it should be [-3]

Comment: @BloxyBloxy please look at the edit..

Answer (score 0):

In handling these examples, we assume that:

- the binary operators are left-associative
- the unary operators are prefix
  Normally, you would also have to take into account precedence of binary operators. Once you do that, you start needing to build an expression tree. To build the tree, the parser starts needing more state variables to memorise what the previous string was, so that we know what operation to apply it to the current operand.

```py
from math import ceil, floor

UNARY_OPERATORS=dict(
    subtract=lambda rhs: -rhs,
    ceil=lambda rhs: ceil(rhs),
    floor=lambda rhs: floor(rhs))
BINARY_OPERATORS = dict(
    add=lambda lhs, rhs: lhs + rhs,
    subtract=lambda lhs, rhs: lhs - rhs,
    multiply=lambda lhs, rhs: lhs * rhs,
    divide=lambda lhs, rhs: lhs / rhs)
BINARY_OPERATOR_PRECEDENCE=[['multiply', 'divide'], ['add','subtract']]


class EvaluatableExpression:
    def evaluate(self):
        return 0.0


class NumericExpression(EvaluatableExpression):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.numeric_value = float(number)
 
    def evaluate(self):
        return self.numeric_value


class UnaryExpression(EvaluatableExpression):
    def __init__(self, oper_name, expression):
        self.operation = UNARY_OPERATORS[oper_name]
        self.expression = expression
 
    def evaluate(self):
        return self.operation(self.expression.evaluate())


class BinaryExpression(EvaluatableExpression):
     def __init__(self, oper, precedence, lhx, rhx):
         self.operation = BINARY_OPERATORS[oper] if isinstance(oper, str)\
             else oper
         self.precedence = precedence
         self.left_expression = lhx
         self.right_expression = rhx

     def evaluate(self):
         return self.operation(self.left_expression.evaluate(), self.right_expression.evaluate())

     @staticmethod
     def BuildBinaryExpression(existing_expression, oper_name, rhx):
         precedence = _estimate_precedence(oper_name)
         if not isinstance(existing_expression, BinaryExpression):
             # first binary expression, no need for precedence comparison
             return BinaryExpression(
                 oper_name,
                 precedence, 
                 existing_expression,
                 rhx)
         elif existing_expression.precedence < precedence or\
                 not isinstance(existing_expression, BinaryExpression):
             # create new top of tree
             return BinaryExpression(
                 oper_name,
                 precedence,
                 existing_expression,
                 rhx)
         else:
             # keep existing expression at top of tree
             existing_lhx = existing_expression.left_expression
             existing_rhx = existing_expression.right_expression
             new_child_expression = BinaryExpression(
                 oper_name,
                 precedence,
                 existing_rhx,
                 rhx)
             return BinaryExpression(
                 existing_expression.operation, 
                 existing_expression.precedence, 
                 existing_lhx, 
                 new_child_expression) 


def _estimate_precedence(oper_name):
     i=0
     for og in BINARY_OPERATOR_PRECEDENCE:
         if oper_name in og:
             return i
         else:
             i = i + 1


class ExpressionParser:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lhx = None
        self.next_unary_operator = None
        self.next_binary_operator = None

    def build_from_list(self, ar_list):
        for item in ar_list:
            assert(isinstance(item, str))
            assert(len(item.strip()) > 0)
            if self.looks_like_binary_operator(item):
                self.next_binary_operator = item
            elif self.looks_like_unary_operator(item):
                self.next_unary_operator = item
            elif self.looks_like_operand(item):
                rhx = NumericExpression(item)
                self._handle_binary_expression(rhx)

    def looks_like_binary_operator(self, item):
        return  item in BINARY_OPERATORS and\
             self.next_binary_operator is None and self.lhx is not None

    def looks_like_unary_operator(self, item):
        return item in UNARY_OPERATORS and self.next_unary_operator is None

    def looks_like_operand(self, item):
         return item[0].isdigit()

    def _handle_binary_expression(self, rhx):
        if self.next_unary_operator:
            # apply unary operator
            rhx = UnaryExpression(self.next_unary_operator, rhx)
            self.next_unary_operator = None

         # try binary operator after unary one
        if self.next_binary_operator:
            self.lhx = BinaryExpression.BuildBinaryExpression(
                 self.lhx,
                 self.next_binary_operator,
                 rhx)
            self.next_binary_operator = None
        if self.lhx is None:
            self.lhx = rhx


def iterate_arithmetic_list(ar_list):
    parser = ExpressionParser()
    parser.build_from_list(ar_list)

    return parser.lhx.evaluate()
```